# How can I define a custom sklearn Pipeline with fixed steps?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a scikit-learn Pipeline object with fixed steps, i.e. a PipelineWithFixedSteps(Pipeline) object that inherits from Pipeline, so that I can instantiate it with a simple call PipelineWithFixedSteps() and keep my code clean.

I noticed that if I create several instances of PipelineWithFixedSteps() and I set the parameters of one of them, the parameters of all instances are modified.

Is this an intended behaviour or am I missing something? What could be an alternative way of defining a shortcut for a Pipeline with fixed steps?

I am using sklearn 0.22.1

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

class PipelineWithFixedSteps(Pipeline):    
    def __init__(
        self,
        steps = [
            ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
            ('linear', LinearRegression()),
        ]
    ):
        super().__init__(steps=steps)

a = PipelineWithFixedSteps()
print(a.get_params())

a.set_params(scaler__with_std=False)
print(a.get_params())

# Create a new instance of PipelineWithFixedNames()
# The new instance has the same parameters as a
b = PipelineWithFixedSteps()
print(b.get_params())

# Set the parameters of b
# The parameters of a are also changed
b.set_params(scaler__with_mean=False)
print(a.get_params())
```

Answer (score 3):

This really has nothing to do with sklearn but boils down to how default values of parameters are interpreted in Python (cf. e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/5085211)), and it sounds like you are trying to do something to the extent of

```
class PipelineWithFixedSteps(Pipeline):    
    def __init__(self, steps=None):
        if steps is None:
            steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('linear', LinearRegression())]
        super().__init__(steps=steps)
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the point and your solution would work in principle. Unfortunately If I want the PipelineWithFixedSteps() to be fully compatible with sklearn, then the __init__() cannot contain any logic (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html).